# DynamoDb pagination Query in java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to dynamo db. I have to implement pagination. I have to show ten records in my html page. I am completely new to dynamo db. Can any one share any sample query for pagination in dynamo db. I have studied amazon dynamo db tutorial but i did not get any idea.
Can i implement pagination using highlevel and lowlevel api? can any one suggest where to start??

Answer (score 4):

As yegor256 suggested, you could use query(QueryRequest) or scan(ScanRequest) with **setExclusiveStartKey** instead. Here's a code snippet of how to do it

```
HashMap<String, Condition> scanFilter = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
Condition condition = new Condition()
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LT.toString())
            .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN("100"));
scanFilter.put("column1", condition);
Boolean lastEval = true;
int count = 0;
ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest(tableName).withScanFilter(scanFilter);
while(lastEval) {
    ScanResult scanResult = dynamoDB.scan(scanRequest);
    count += scanResult.getCount();
    System.out.println("Page Size: " + scanResult.getCount());
    System.out.println("Total count = " + count);
    if (scanResult.getLastEvaluatedKey() != null)
        lastEval = scanResult.getLastEvaluatedKey().isEmpty() == false;
    else
        lastEval = false;
    if (lastEval) {
        scanRequest.setExclusiveStartKey(scanResult.getLastEvaluatedKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `query(QueryRequest)` or `scan(ScanRequest)` with [`addExclusiveStartKeyEntry()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/QueryRequest.html#addExclusiveStartKeyEntry)

Also, check this library: [jcabi-dynamo](http://dynamo.jcabi.com)