# AWS Lambda and AWS Dynamodb: Scanned count is less than item count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Table `events` contains 3700+ items. When I scan through it, it only returns 791 item counts. Why is that?

Here's the code in `Lambda`:

```
var doc = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new doc.DynamoDB();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        TableName: "events",
        ProjectionExpression: "event, #date",
        FilterExpression: "event = :value",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#date": "date" },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":value": { S: "hurricane" } }
    };
    db.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

> { Items: [],   Count: 0,   ScannedCount: 791,   LastEvaluatedKey: {
>   date: { N: '1499875896175' } } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of the Scan result set is larger than 1 MB, then ScannedCount and Count will represent only a partial count of the total items. You will need to perform multiple Scan operations in order to retrieve all of the results ([see Paginating the Results](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination)).

Is that Lambda in Node.js? Here is an [example of pagination in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772102/dynamodb-pagination-query-in-java)